# phonegap run android error

Tags: android, cordova

Whenever I try to build a project using `phonegap run`, I get the below error:

```
C:\Users\MS AwaN\my-app>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

C:\Users\MS AwaN\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\MS AwaN\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\MS AwaN\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\MS AwaN\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\MS AwaN\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\MS AwaN\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\MS AwaN\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\MS AwaN\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: run `phonegap run android -d` This will give you more specific output on the error. Post some of that output here as it may be more useful than above.

Comment: still the same output occurs.

Comment: uninstall all your plugins. one of the might cause the pain.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438218/cannot-get-ant-installed-properly-for-phonegap-using-eclipse-and-windows-8) fixed it. Alternately look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576704/phonegap-cordova-android-development) (which is the same but has a link to the documentation which I also missed).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that phonegap 3.3 requires android sdk 19.

If you have a older one, try the following steps :

1. delete the platforms/android folder (as the log say "Adding the android platform", I assume you didn't perform any customisations in that folder)
2. use android sdk manager to install the latest sdk
3. retry with `phonegap build android` and if it fails, run `phonegap -V build android` to get more details on the error