# Installing PhoneGap, error executing command 'ant'

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ant

When installing PhoneGap via nodeJS i got an error when trying to run my app (installing phonegap and creating the app worked):

```
C:\Users\arko\my-app>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
    [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

C:\Users\arko\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add
ed to your path.
    at C:\Users\arko\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:47
:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

So I noticed I never had ANT installed, so I did. I followed this tutorial: http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.nl/2012/11/how-to-install-phonegap-for-android.html and done everything it said.

The part it says you have to add stuff to the Path variable, it said just add this: %ANT_HOME%\bin; however my Path ended with this: C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared - so I added this to it: ;%ANT_HOME%\bin;

Tried to run the android app again, and got the same error. I ran it with this command:

```
phonegap run android
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Also ensure you reopen your command prompt after you set the environment variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576704/phonegap-cordova-android-development

Answer (score 5):

Probably you have a new version of cordova, i saw that in a partner machine was installed the cordova version 3.5.0 and in my machine it was installed the 3.4.0 version, maybe the ant version is incompatible with the new version of cordova (He and i has the ant version 1.9.4) .

Try install a old version of cordova with this command in the node.js console:

```
    npm install -g cordova@3.4.0-0.1.0
```

and run the command again.

Other cause: Verify that your Path Variables are configured correctly..

My english is not pretty good, but i hope help you to solve the problem.

Comment: @Vladius That's Great!!

Answer (score 3):

```
Variable: ANDROID_HOME Value: C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk

Variable: ANT_HOME Value: C:\Development\apache-ant-1.9.2

Variable: JAVA_HOME Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
```

then define system paths

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;
```

reboot your computer

[Cannot get ant installed properly for phonegap using eclipse and windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438218/cannot-get-ant-installed-properly-for-phonegap-using-eclipse-and-windows-8)

Comment: Avoid space bar for each parameter after semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Set the path for `ant` in your system variables, and use that variable path in your user variables.
After setting both, restart your computer so they take effect.

User variables:

```
PATH = %ANT_HOME%/bin
```

System variables:

```
ANT_HOME = c:\your directory
```

such as

```
ANT_HOME = C:\ant
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check what you set ANT_HOME to, you can do that by opening a "command prompt" (Start -> Run -> CMD) and type `echo %ANT_HOME%`

Check if this is the correct directory that you have ANT installed into, otherwise set it. (The URL you linked to tells you how).

You can verify the ANT "installation" by typeing `ant -version` in a "command prompt" window.

Comment: C:\Users\arko>echo %ANT_HOME%
C:\Program Files\ANT\apache-ant-1.9.3

C:\Users\arko>ant -version
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\li
b\tools.jar
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013

C:\Users\arko>

Comment: Seems the JRE doesn't include the **tools.jar** file, you have to download and install the JDK, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618281/ant-error-when-trying-to-build-file-cant-find-tools-jar

Answer (score 0):

¿Did you create JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME variables? ¿Did you also add to the PATH?

Comment: Note: you will need to open a new command prompt to pick up changed variables.
The PATH variable needs to include "%ANT_HOME%\bin", "%JDK_HOME%\bin", "%ANDROID_SDK%\tools" and "%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools". Note that the variable names ANT_HOME, JDK_HOME and ANDROID_SDK are arbitrary, and of course must be set to be used, else the full paths can be used to set the PATH variable. eg PATH={...other_stuff...};C:\data\dev\Apache\Ant\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\data\dev\Android\android-sdk\tools;C
:\data\dev\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the ant variable `ANT_HOME`, just insert the absolute path in your windows system variable `PATH` like this:

```
c:\yourDirectory\ant\bin;
```

Then it should work/run fine!