# cordova add platform - Error executing command 'ant'

Tags: android, cordova, ant

### In the beginning..

I know that this question has been asked way too many times and.. I checked all ansers on SO. Tried every combination and every solution I found but nothing has worked for me so far.

---

### The problem

I've succesfully installed cordova downloading it from the official site and I've been following the Guide.

I've added `wp8` platform *succesfully* first. Then I tried to add android as well.

After executing the command `cordova platform add android`, I got the following error.

```
Error: executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
```

Here's a screenshot with more details:

[image: Error: executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.]

---

### My efforts

I've installed ANT, the last Java JDK and added all necessary Enviroment Variables to my System.

ANT and JAVA both gets executed fine from any source path.

`ant -version` outputs

> Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014

`java -version` outputs

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

---

### Enviroment Variables

I've set up every necessary variable. From ANT_HOME to PATH. Everything is as it should be

```
ANT_HOME: C:\Program Files\Ant 

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05

ANDROID_HOME: C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Cellulare\Development\sdk

PATH: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;
```

As everyone can see, I've also added android `platform-tools` and `tools` to my `PATH`. Same thing for Ant and Java (\bin dirs).

Needless to say but every path is correct.

---

Having this things said, Why this still doesn't work? I've also restarted my PC as well but with no results.

---

## Solution

Thanks to [**Kerri Shotts**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741043/kerri-shotts).

My problems were from those spaces in my paths.

So I changed `C:\Program Files\...` to `C:\Progra~1\...`.

**IMPORTANT!**

I also noticed there were 2 `□` characters in my strings. Like this `..\C□□ellulare\..`. They probably came from a wrong copy-paste format. After fixing these things everything worked!

Comment: Just pick in sky - try set path without shortcuts.

Comment: @Astery Doesn't work. Still same error

Comment: Might be those pesky spaces. Try using the 8.3 short filename trick (Something like C:\PROGRA~1\ANT...)

Comment: @KerriShotts: `C:\Program~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;C:\Program~1\Ant\bin;C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Cellulare\Development\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Cellulare\Development\sdk\tools;` doesn't work. Still SAME error. That's ridiculous isn't it?

Comment: Make sure you use the correct 8.3 name -- "Program~1" is 9 characters, not 8. I can't tell you for certain what the 8.3 name will be, but a `dir /x` from `c:` should tell you what to use.

Comment: @KerriShotts Gotcha! Yep, spaces caused that. And ALSO some "hidden characters" in my string. It's hard to explain but between two letters there were 2 characters. Of course they were hidden but moving the cursor with the arrows I found them. Now I'm dowloading API 19 but that error is gone. Man if you post it as an answer I give you what you deserve. So others can be helped too

Comment: Update ended up. Everything works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: One should also try this solution, which seems to have helped myself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24684283/289912

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of languages, whitespaces are executed in some whilst ignored in others.
Utilizing a file name such as "Program(whitespace)Files" does produce errors when compiling from \bin directories.
Next time you declare an environmental variable, be sure that your  folder does not contain any whitespaces or gaps between the various names. 
FYI: camelCase scripts where introduced tow work around this concept.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Like in my case developers have to pay attention to "invisible" characters between words from a bad "copy-paste" behavior