# How to add android cmd to windows 8.1 system path ? (cordova application)

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ant, cmd

I have a windows 8.1 Os. I have installed **cordova, android sdk, java sdk and apache ant.
I can create a cordova application but when i try to use this command "**cordova platform add android**". i have this error: **Error: Failed to run "android". Make sure you have the latest Android SDK instal
led, and that the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your
PATH.** 
here is my system path : "**C:\nodejs;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%/bin;C:\adt-bundle\platform-tools;C:\adt-bundle\tools;C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm**"
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438218/cannot-get-ant-installed-properly-for-phonegap-using-eclipse-and-windows-8)

Comment: Thank you for the link but the problem still the same @Lepanto

Comment: try to run the following command and see if there's more details in the logs : `%USERPROFILE%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova \3.4.0\windows8\bin\check_reqs.bat`  (replace 3.4.0 with the actual version of cordova you're using) And also, do you have spaces in your windows user name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type 'android' (no quotes) in your cmd window it should bring up the Android SDK Manager. If it does, you need to ensure you have the latest Android SDK tools, Android SDK Patfom-tools, and Android SDK buil tools installed.

Comment: when i type 'android' ( no quotes) in my cmd. Android SDK Manager lunch automactly @Sam

Comment: I have the latest Android Sdk (API 21)